# node modules get the latest commits

Tags: git, github, node-modules

how do I have node_modules download the latest commits from a package? I'm using one that committed a fix, but they haven't yet published a new version.
In my dependencies I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "somepackage": "^2",
```

Do I need to change it to something else? like adding @latest or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `devel` or `feature` branch, or you haven’t published a certain package to the NPM registry, or you can’t because it's a private module, then you can point to a `git://` URI instead of a version number in your `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
   "public": "git://github.com/user/repo.git#ref",
   "private": "git+ssh://git@github.com:user/repo.git#ref"
}
```

The `#ref` portion is optional, and it can be a branch (like `master`), tag (like `0.0.1`) or a partial or full commit id.

Comment: I see. So there's no way to commit the latest version WITH the latest commit without specifying the commit ID?

Comment: try "package": "git://package.git#commit"

Comment: OK, so the answer is no. There is no way to get the latest commit without specifying it, or did I misunderstand? If so, could you please provide an example and not a "templated" example?